# Devise undefined method `email'

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

Whenever I hit the sign in button I get the following error:

```
NoMethodError in Devise/sessions#new

Showing /Users/chanel.n/svn-    work/gwb/trunk/PMOCCU/ProcessEnforcer/app/views/devise/sessions/new.html.erb where line #5 raised:

undefined method `email' for #<User id: nil, name: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
Extracted source (around line #5):

2: 
3: <%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
4:   <div class="field"><%= f.label :email %><br />
5:   <%= f.email_field :email %></div>
6: 
7:   <div class="field"><%= f.label :password %><br />
8:   <%= f.password_field :password %></div>
Rails.root: /Users/chanel.n/svn-work/gwb/trunk/PMOCCU/ProcessEnforcer

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/views/devise/sessions/new.html.erb:5:in `block in    _app_views_devise_sessions_new_html_erb___4179931318693150703_70215900182100'
app/views/devise/sessions/new.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_devise_sessions_new_html_erb___4179931318693150703_70215900182100'
```

Here is my User Model which includes email:

```
class User < Role
has_and_belongs_to_many :roles

attr_accessible :name, :roles

# Include default devise modules. Others available are:
# :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
# :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable, :validatable, :token_authenticatable

# Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
attr_protected :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :department, :encrypted_password 
# attr_accessible :title, :body, :remember_me

 validates_presence_of :email

end
```

For whatever reason, it it not recognizing email.

Has anyone else run into this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your email field is not accessible in the User model,You should make it accessible by using:

```
attr_accessible :name, :roles, :email
```

Answer (score 0):

Devise by default uses email as the login so it requires you to have the :email and :encrypted_password fields.

You don't have either in your User model. So, you need to add those fields.

Comment: I do have email in my User model.

Comment: I added the user model above.

Answer (score 0):

The other suggestions were not relevant in my case. My version of devise was out of date. Upgrading to 3.2.4 fixed it for me.

The main issue was seemingly that the migration that devise generates is different in the newer version.